# Can anyone correct this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to execute this code. I have tried many times but remained unsuccessful.

```js
<html>
<head><title>
alvin</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var voting age = window.prompt("please enter your age");
if(voting age>=18)
{
    document.write("you are eligible to vote");
}
else
{
    document.write("you are not eligible to vote");
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript does not support identifiers with spaces.

Comment: Yes, we can. Instead, though, how 'bout reading up on JavaScript so *you* can correct it? Hint: JavaScript variable names cannot contain spaces. (This is almost universally true of programming languages, in fact, not just JavaScript.)

Comment: variable names can not have spaces in them. I hope the exam isn't a javascript one

Comment: come on guys be soft upon him he's just a kid with exams on head.

Comment: `just a kid` - adults can take exams too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calm down kid don't cooked up in exams tension the only thing you need to know is that variables can't have space so i just replaced `voting age` with `voting_age`

```
<html>
<head><title>
alvin</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var voting_age = window.prompt("please enter your age");
if(voting_age>=18)
{
    document.write("you are eligible to vote");
}
else
{
    document.write("you are not eligible to vote");
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```